# Android hybrid app - api response time issue

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

I am making a android hybrid app and using REST api.
My desktop application is running fast and apis response time are low but same apis in hybrid app are taking too much time.

My desktop api response time is 100-150ms but in hybrid app, apis response time are 1-2sec.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: your device is running under wifi?

Comment: 1. Get a http proxy like wireshark or Charles and make sure that the same calls from your desktop vs hybrid app have a similar response time. 2. Profile your hybrid app and figure out what is slow.